# My windows pc is not starting, can i use ubuntu to rescue files?

Tags: files

If I use the DVD image to try ubuntu and my pc opens, will I be able to find my files on the hard drive and save to a back up external hard drive or will they be locked in to some windows-y place that I can't get to.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Ubuntu Live CD/DVD/USB is often used as a rescue disk. You have to simply use the option `Try Ubuntu` while booting from Live CD/DVD/USB.

Once Ubuntu opened you have to open/mount the hard drive to get you data back or to save it to any other storage.

Comment: Thanks Saurav I'm trying now.  What does mount mean?

Comment: `mount` means just opening the drive. For example in windows `C:` drive it would be `/dev/sda1` in Ubuntu. You'll not get any difficulty. You can easily mount by click the icon on left side of any file manager.

Comment: @AndyBrady: you can reply any time, if you want any help. Believe me it is very simple to mount your hard drive if its not mounted automatically. When you'll open `My Computer` or `Files` in Ubunut, the left-side pane will list all your drives those were listed in Windows. You've to simply click it (or right click -> `mount`) to mount the drives. ;)

Comment: sorted - cheers!

Comment: Sounds good..! I'm so glad to help you..!!

Comment: @AndyBrady: I want from you to mark this post as solved so that it will help others to get through the same situation. So for that you've to accept my answer.